# Joins with ActiveAndroid - how to get second table's data

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I'm using ActiveAndroid and running a query with an outer join:

```
List<NavigationState> models = new Select()
                    .from(NavigationState.class)
                    .leftJoin(BundleItem.class)
                    .on("aColumnName = anotherColumnName")
                    .execute();
```

So obviously what I want is NavigationStates, with any associated BundleItems.  What I actually get is NavigationStates.  Here's the part of the ActiveAndroid code that fills in the data from a cursor after running a query:

```
List<String> columnsOrdered = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cursor.getColumnNames()));
                do {
                    Model entity = Cache.getEntity(type, cursor.getLong(columnsOrdered.indexOf(idName)));
                    if (entity == null) {
                        entity = (T) entityConstructor.newInstance();
                    }

                    entity.loadFromCursor(cursor);
                    entities.add((T) entity);
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        }
```

You can see the whole thing, it's the `processCursor` method, here: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/blob/df29214c9584d7b626f361e95b95daccb0c0114c/src/com/activeandroid/util/SQLiteUtils.java

So as you can see, it makes no attempt to do anything but fill in the type that was passed in (`loadFromCursor` doesn't fill in anything from other tables either).  I even switched it to ask for a list of `BundleItem` and it apparently still returned the same thing.

The only thing the AA documentation says about getting the "many" records from the many side of a one-to-many relationship is to call `Model.getMany`, but that runs its own query (one for each record in the result set!), so if I do that there's no point in doing a join in the first query.

Am I missing something, because it seems like joins are allowed with ActiveAndroid, but not useful, since you can only get results from one of the tables in the join?  I can work around it in this case but I'm wondering if I picked the wrong ORM, because this seems like a pretty basic feature that's broken.